# Find a file in lots of zip files (like find command for directories)

Tags: linux, files, find, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find recursively all archive files of diverse archive formats and search them for file name patterns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42379/find-recursively-all-archive-files-of-diverse-archive-formats-and-search-them-fo)

I need to search for a file in all zip files in a directory.

Is there a tool like `find` that be able to search in ZIP files?

I tried this:

```
find /path/ -iname '*.zip' -print -exec unzip -l {} \; |grep -i '<filename>'
```

But this only prints path of file in zip file and not the zip file name itself!

Thanks

Comment: That's why I added the 'echo' to my command.

Comment: `for f in *.zip; do echo "$f: "; less $f | grep <filename>; done`, according to:
https://superuser.com/questions/216617/view-list-of-files-in-zip-archive-on-linux

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try:

```
for f in *.zip; do echo "$f: "; unzip -l $f | grep <filename>; done
```

Comment: Hi; Thanks; Your command makes lots of mass output (because of file date,... that `ls` prints)! but changing it to this solved the problem:  `for f in *.zip; do echo "$f: "; unzip -l $f | grep -i <file_name>; done` Thank you again.

Comment: for f in *.zip; do unzip -l $f | grep <filename> && echo $f; done ... Better this way ? :)

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

Comment: Also fails on filenames with a space in them if I put the code into a script

Comment: the same thing , but IMHO more user-friendly : 
 while read -r zip_file ; do echo $zip_file ; unzip -l $zip_file | grep -i --color=always -R $to_srch; done < <(find . -name '*.zip') | less -R

Comment: Just recommend to set `unzip -l "$f"` with quotation marks so there is no issue with files with spaces...